# How the value of denominator calculated here?

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions

I found this example in a book and it has to find probability distribution as stated below:

If a car agency sells 50% of its inventory of a certain foreign car equipped with
side airbags, find a formula for the probability distribution of the number of cars
with side airbags among the next 4 cars sold by the agency.
Solution : Since the probability of selling an automobile with side airbags is 0.5, the $2^4 = 16$
points in the sample space are equally likely to occur. Therefore, the denominator
for all probabilities, and also for our function, is 16.

I am not able to understand by what formula the value in denominator is coming as 16, yes I can see it is taken as power of 2 but why? What if the probability would be 30% how we would have calculated this?

Answer (score 3):

It's actually $(0.5)^4=(\frac12)^4=\frac{1}{16}$ That's why the denominator is 16.
So if it's 30%, then it's $(0.3)^4$